# I would like to show a message for whatever http response I get using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, http

So I have a message to be displayed on my html shortly after there's a page redirect. How can I use javascript to achieve this. Basically, I need to know when the current page receives any sort of response, then write a function for that state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you receive the response, if you check the status code you will have some series based on the response, suppose if its success it will be 200 series, and with that you write the logic,

example:

```
fetch("url").then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // your function goes here
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My situation is that I used Django for the request, not JavaScript. I have an animation that activates upon redirecting, but I want to stop it once the page redirects to another page. As it is, it is a looped animation, so when user clicks the back button, the animation is still activated and they couldn't see the page. JavaScript will assist in this regards.